# Digits Javascript SDK Consumer Key

Tags: twitter, twitter-fabric

Hi I couldn't find Digits javascript sdk consumer key.  I followed the guide and all it led me to is https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/web/digits  in here it says

> You can find it in your Fabric web dashboard under the Twitter Kit tab (Digits does not work with keys created from apps.twitter.com).

But under the web dashboard all it has https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/web/digits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to get a consumer key for Digits at the moment is through the Xcode SDK or Android SDK as mentioned here https://twittercommunity.com/t/using-digits-for-website-only/33550

Although this may change in the future

Comment: Thanks for coming back and answering  your own question, this  problem was driving me nuts ! How can they not tell this. The key was first before they came up with the sdks.